# Solve this trigonometric inequality

Tags: trigonometry, inequality

The values of $\lambda$ for which the equation $2\sin (x)-\sqrt \lambda \cos(x)=\sqrt2+\sqrt{2-\lambda}$ has solutions.

MY APPROOACH:

Now I know that max value of LHS of above expression can be $\sqrt{4+\lambda}$ and min value can be $\sqrt{4-\lambda}$. So $\sqrt2+\sqrt{2-\lambda}\in [\sqrt{4-\lambda},\sqrt{4+\lambda}]$. So I get $\lambda \ge \frac{1}{2}$. Now how do I find the max value because I am unable to get a conclusion from $\sqrt{4+\lambda}\ge \sqrt2+\sqrt{2-\lambda}$

Comment: Is it an equation or an inequality?

Comment: I think it is both but when i wrote equation in topic it said another question of same name exists, hence I changed it to inequality.

Comment: And you want to find $\lambda$ such that the equation has solutions?

Comment: @CYKwong Yes.Why is there any problem there?

Comment: You haven't stated that. The sentence ended with the equation.

Comment: @CYKwong Sorry I forgot,let me edit.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/58522/discussion-between-savitar-and-cy-kwong).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Obviously, we need $-4\le\lambda\le2$.
\begin{align*}
\sqrt{4+\lambda}&\ge\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{2-\lambda}\\
4+\lambda&\ge2+2\sqrt{2(2-\lambda)}+2-\lambda\\
\lambda&\ge \sqrt{4-2\lambda} \qquad\qquad (\text{Note: this implies that }\lambda\ge0)\\
\lambda^2&\ge4-2\lambda\\
(\lambda+1)^2&\ge5\\
\lambda+1&\ge\sqrt{5}\\
\lambda&\ge\sqrt{5}-1
\end{align*}

So $\sqrt{5}-1\le \lambda\le2$.

Answer (score 0):

HINT: use that $$\sin(x)=2\,{\frac {\tan \left( x/2 \right) }{1+ \left( \tan \left( x/2
 \right)  \right) ^{2}}}
$$
and $$\cos(x)={\frac {1- \left( \tan \left( x/2 \right)  \right) ^{2}}{1+ \left( 
\tan \left( x/2 \right)  \right) ^{2}}}
$$
and set $$\tan(x/2)=t$$ 
solve your equation for $t$

Comment: Now i got a quadratic equation in $t$ but it contains both $\lambda$ and $t$. So should i solve for Discriminant $\ge 0$?

Comment: this equation must you solve for $t$ and you must consider the discriminant if you want real Solutions in $t$